# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fdd43044d90>

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm doing a simple To-Do List in python 3.6.7 with django 2.0.7 in a virtualenv in Ubuntu,this error appeared when I created a folder called static with a css folder with styles(static/css/styles.css) I changed  settings.py and added this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

More later I created a link in my base.html to the styles:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />`

And this is my console output:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4061a4bd90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/mario/Dev/ToDo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 101, in check_url_settings
    if value and not value.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `settings.py`, check if either your `STATIC_URL` or `MEDIA_URL` settings has a trailing comma after them. It seems that your code is mistaking them for a tuple.